# deployment problems with visual studio 2012 and mvc4

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, iis

I am using the default iis of win 8.1 with visual studio 2012 and mvc4.    I already have achieved deploy it locally in my intranet with the option of file system, but not all my ActionResult methods are executed.  te server tell me that it can not find the specified path. but when I run it from visual studio  locally everything works perfectly. if someone could help me because I'm pretty new to all this.

Comment: Can you share some code and error details as well. Particularly for the methods that you are receiving errors in.

Comment: sure hold on a minute

Comment: 1. Do You have IIS installed correctly?
2. Do You have ASP.NET registered?
3. Did You created IIS directory as application in configuration?

Comment: i am back well it was  my partner who do all that so if you can tall me how can i check that i have the asp.net registered and all related with your last question

Comment: the error is the typical 404 not found

Comment: yes it is registered and the iis directory is created as application

Comment: can you check in network  tab where it is showing 404 not found and check the url which it is accessing . problem may be due to path setting (which always works great locally tough ).